# Show a tick/message over a bundled product when the product is already in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, product-attribute

I am showing custom products on the product page using this code:

```
<?php
    $bundle_products = $_product->getbundle_products();
    if ($_product->getAttributeText('bundle') == yes):
    $product_ids = explode(',',$bundle_products);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $product_ids));

    foreach($collection as $eachproduct){
        echo '<a href="' . $eachproduct->getProductUrl() . '"><img  src="' . $eachproduct->getImageUrl() . '" title="' . $eachproduct->getName() . '" height="50" width="50"></a>';
        $combined_price += $eachproduct->getFinalPrice()/100*$_product->getamos_bundle_discount();
    }
    endif;
?>
```

This works perfectly but what I want is to get cart information and if the bundle product is already in the cart it will have a tick overlay/message beside it. I can sort the design out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the product ids in the cart like this:

```
$ids = array();
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $ids[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getProductId(); //used array key here to avoid duplicates
}
```

Now you just need to get the bundle product id using `$productId = $eachproduct->getId()` and check

```
if (isset($ids[$productId])) {
    //product in cart
}
```

Comment: Can you show this in my code?

Comment: Put the first part of my code above your code, and the second part where you want to insert the tick. inside a foreach loop I assume.